# c++ referenced variable issue

Tags: c++, variables, scope, reference

Working on a homework assignment. Have gotten it all the way to the end, but last point won't work. I cannot figure out why this referenced variable won't work like the others.
Variables in question: set1Correct, set2Correct, set3Correct
I've tested in the various functions in which they are used, and they pull the right number of correct answers, but when used in printReport() they can't seem to reference correctly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<ctime>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;

void getProbsPerSet(int&);
void doOneSet(char,int);
void getMaxNum (int&);
void doOneProblem(char,int&,int&, int&, int&, int&, int&, int&);
void generateOperands (int&,int&,int&);
void printHeader(char &);
void checkAnswer(char&, int&, int&, int&, int&, int&, int&, int&);
void printReport(int&, int&, int&, int&);

int main()
{

    int probperset;
    int set1Correct, set2Correct, set3Correct;

    srand(time(0));
    getProbsPerSet(probperset);
    doOneSet('+',probperset);
    doOneSet('-',probperset);
    doOneSet('*',probperset);
    printReport(set1Correct, set2Correct, set3Correct, probperset);


 return 0;   
}


void printHeader(char &mathType)
{
    int setCount = 0;
    //determine set# print
    if(mathType == '+')
        setCount = 1;
    if(mathType == '-')
        setCount = 2;
    if(mathType == '*')
        setCount = 3;

     cout << endl;
     cout  << "Set#" << setCount << endl;
     cout << "---------" << endl << endl;
}

void getProbsPerSet(int& probperset)
{
     cout << " Enter problems per set: ";
     cin >> probperset;
     cout << endl;
}

void generateOperands(int& num1,int& num2,int& maxNum)
{
   num1 = (rand() % maxNum + 1);
   num2 = (rand() % maxNum + 1);
}


void getMaxNum(int& max)
{
     cout << " What is the maximum number for this set? ";
     cin >> max;
     cout << endl;
}

void checkAnswer(char &mathType, int &num1, int &num2, int &num3, int &set1Correct, int &set2Correct, int &set3Correct)
{
       if(mathType == '+')
        {
          if(num3 == num1 + num2)
          {
          cout << "correct" << endl;
          set1Correct = set1Correct +1; 
          //cout << set1Correct;
          }
          else cout << "incorrect" << endl;
        }

        if(mathType == '-')
        {
          if(num3 == num1 - num2)
          {
          cout << "correct" << endl;
          set2Correct = set2Correct + 1; 
          //cout << set2Correct;
          }
          else cout << "incorrect" << endl;
        }

        if(mathType == '*')
        {
            if(num3 == num1 * num2)
            {
            cout << "correct" << endl;
            set3Correct = set3Correct + 1; 
            //cout << set3Correct;
            }
            else cout << "incorrect" << endl;
        }

}


void doOneProblem (char mathType,int& num1, int& num2, int& num3, int& set1Correct, int& set2Correct, int& set3Correct)
{

    switch(mathType)
       {
        case '+' : cout << num1 <<  mathType << num2 << "= ";
                   cin >> num3;
                   cout << endl;
                   checkAnswer(mathType, num1, num2, num3, set1Correct, set2Correct, set3Correct);
                   break;
        case '-' : cout << num1 <<  mathType << num2 << "= ";
                   cin >> num3;
                   cout << endl;
                  checkAnswer(mathType, num1, num2, num3, set1Correct, set2Correct, set3Correct);
                   break;
        case '*' : cout << num1 <<  mathType << num2 << "= ";
                   cin >> num3;
                   cout << endl;
                   checkAnswer(mathType, num1, num2, num3, set1Correct, set2Correct, set3Correct);               
                   break;
        default: cout << "error" << endl;;
                   break;
        }    

}




void doOneSet (char mathType, int probperset)
{ 
  printHeader (mathType);
  int maxNum;
  int num1 = 0;
  int num2 = 0;
  int num3 = 0;
  int set1Correct = 0;
  int set2Correct = 0;
  int set3Correct = 0;
  getMaxNum (maxNum);

     for ( int counter = 1;counter <= probperset; counter++)
     {  
        generateOperands (num1, num2,maxNum);

       switch(mathType)
           {
        case '+' : doOneProblem(mathType,num1,num2, num3,set1Correct, set2Correct, set3Correct);
                   break;
        case '-' : doOneProblem(mathType,num1,num2, num3, set1Correct, set2Correct, set3Correct);
                   break;
        case '*' : doOneProblem(mathType,num1,num2, num3, set1Correct, set2Correct, set3Correct);
                   break;
        default: cout << "error" << endl;
                   break;

       }
   }
}

void printReport(int &probperset, int &set1Correct, int &set2Correct, int &set3Correct)
{
   float avg1 = (set1Correct/probperset); 
   float avg2 = (set2Correct/probperset); 
   float avg3 = (set3Correct/probperset); 

    cout << avg1 << " " << avg2 << " " << avg3;

    /*cout << "Set#1:  You got " << set1Correct << "correct out of ";
    cout << probperset << "for " << avg1 << "%" << endl;
    cout << "Set#2:  You got " << set2Correct << "correct out of ";
    cout << probperset << "for " << avg2 << "%" << endl;
    cout << "Set#3:  You got " << set3Correct << "correct out of ";
    cout << probperset << "for " << avg3 << "%" << endl;
    //Overall you got 5 correct out of 9 for 56%
  */
}
```

Comment: In the function definition, `probperset` is the first parameter. But when you are calling it, you pass it last. Then parameter names and values are all mixed up.

Comment: Don't use unnecessary references.

Comment: I'm not sure which of those wouldn't be necessary. The info is all from other functions, so to snag that info they're references. I've tried removing the & throughout so that it's not reference variables, and it still doesn't work.

Comment: *Also re-ordered parameters so that they match, but it still does not properly  reference the variables

Comment: What isn't working about it?

Comment: it doesn't seem to be pulling the reference. It will list the first as 0, and the second two as other random numbers. It acts like it is pulling a reference (no error message), but definitely is not pulling the right thing